# Continuous location details when app is killed/Terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

How to get continuous location details when app is killed/Terminated ?  startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method firing the didUpdateLocations delegate method after 500 meters. But i want location updates in kill mode for every 10 meters. Or i want to relaunch the application in background automatically and start the location updates in background.Currently i have the working code in background.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        [[LocationManager sharedLocarionManager] updateAccuracy:YES];
        [[LocationManager sharedLocarionManager].locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        [[LocationManager sharedLocarionManager].locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [[LocationManager sharedLocarionManager].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [[LocationManager sharedLocarionManager].locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        [[LocationManager sharedLocarionManager].locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    }
    return YES;
}
```

## LocationManager.m

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; // meters
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)updateAccuracy:(BOOL)trackingAccuracy {

    if (trackingAccuracy) {
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter =  10.0 ; // meters
        self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    } else {
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100; // meters
    }

    [ self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

Comment: [See my previous answer hope this may help you :](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41879988/6207973)

Comment: if you are using continous location updation your app will be reject in app store

Comment: @Anbu : I have reason for this My app some thing like uber car tracking. It is required  continous  location update right ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around. Though you cannot get continuous location when your app is killed but you can send silent push notification via server to your user to get the update about its location. You will get 30 second window when the app receives silent push notification. In that short time span, you have to perform your task.

Comment: this method doesn't work. the OS ends up never delivering them if your app isn't foreground. Maybe you'll get the first one... but the 2nd.. 3rd.. 4th.. will never arrive.

Comment: Yes you are right that doesn't work when app is killed